# Laravel cashier : how to get plan name or id?

Tags: php, laravel-5, stripe-payments, billing

I have 8 stripe plans. 4 monthly + 4 yearly. like

```
plan_one.monthly
plan_one.yearly
plan_two.monthly
plan_two.yearly
plan_three.monthly
plan_three.yearly
plan_four.monthly
plan_four.yearly
```

and here is user subscription row

```
id -> 1
user_id -> 1
name -> Plan-One Monthly
stripe_id -> sub_xxxxxxxxxx
stripe_plan -> plan_one.monthly
quantity -> 1
trial_ends_at - null
ends_at - null
created_at - datetime()
updated_at - datetime()
```

In this situation how can i get user active/current subscription plan name?

Comment: You can use either https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_customer (if you just have one subscription) or https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_subscriptions (if you have multiple) to do this.

Comment: Weirdly there is no way to do this in cashier without looping through all of your plans and checking if `$user->subscription($plan_name)` is true. I know it is dumb, but that's how it was built. Ran into this myself yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

The **subscription** method on **Billable** trait setup to return the last row. So if one billable entity only has one active subscription on your app, this works just fine:

```
$user->subscription('default')->stripe_plan;
```

tested on laravel 5.6 / cashier 7.1

Answer (score 2):

I’m late to the party but I was looking for a similar solution, in my case I only allow the user to have one subscription at a time but I wanted to  programmatically fetch the users active subscription without looping through the available subscriptions, reading the laravel docs more throughly I found what I needed using subscription scopes.

$user->subscriptions()->active()->first();

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#subscription-scopes